# Active Appearance Model in java and opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I'm new to opencv. I need to extract facial features to identify happy and sad faces. But haarcascade does not give satisfying results. I need to use AAM/ASM in java. How can I do this?

Comment: 1. You are asking for **too many things**. 2. You are asking **too broad** questions. 3. This is not the right place for what you are asking

Comment: Plus: haarcascade face detection != AAM/ASM

Comment: OpenCV documentation here http://opencv.org/documentation.html

Comment: "Haar Cascade"-based face detection here http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

Comment: KeillRandor, you got this one wrong, it's about finding alternative features for emotion recognition, not cascades (they really don't work for that)

Comment: @berak yeah, I got it wrong from "haarcascade does not give satisfying results" and the question is clear. C'mon..

Comment: aww, sorry if that sounded harsh, not intended.

Comment: @berak What I mean is that I was only posting references about some of the topics this question might be related with. Still, it is unclear and too broad (and probably will be flagged and closed soon..)

Comment: So what could be better alternatives to extract facial features